# NgRx Store does not detect payload correctly in Angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

The problem is that TypeScript thinks that **action.payload.index** is not valid.
I am not sure how to force my project to see this 'index'

shopping-list.actions.ts

```
import {Action} from "@ngrx/store";
import {Ingredient} from "../../shared/ingredient.model";

export const ADD_INGREDIENT = 'ADD_INGREDIENT';
export const ADD_INGREDIENTS = 'ADD_INGREDIENTS';
export const UPDATE_INGREDIENT = 'UPDATE_INGREDIENT';
export const DELETE_INGREDIENT = 'DELETE_INGREDIENT';

export class AddIngredient implements Action {
  readonly type: string = ADD_INGREDIENT;

  constructor(public payload: Ingredient) {
  }
}

export class AddIngredients implements Action {
  readonly type = ADD_INGREDIENTS;

  constructor(public payload: Ingredient[]) {
  }
}

export class UpdateIngredient implements Action {
  readonly type = UPDATE_INGREDIENT;

  constructor(public payload: { index: number, ingredient: Ingredient }) {
  }
}

export class DeleteIngredient implements Action {
  readonly type = DELETE_INGREDIENT;

  constructor(public payload: number) {
  }
}

export type ShoppingListActions = AddIngredient | AddIngredients | UpdateIngredient | DeleteIngredient;
```

shopping-list.reducer.ts

```
import {Ingredient} from "../../shared/ingredient.model";
import * as  ShoppingListActions from "./shopping-list.actions";


const initialState = {
  ingredients: [
    new Ingredient('Apple', 5),
    new Ingredient('Banana', 5)
  ]
};

export function shoppingListReducer(state = initialState, action: ShoppingListActions.ShoppingListActions) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ShoppingListActions.ADD_INGREDIENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        ingredients: [...state.ingredients, action.payload]
      };
    case ShoppingListActions.ADD_INGREDIENTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        ingredients: [...state.ingredients, ...(<Ingredient[]>action.payload)]
      };
    case ShoppingListActions.DELETE_INGREDIENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        ingredients: [...state.ingredients]
      };
    case ShoppingListActions.UPDATE_INGREDIENT:
      const ingredient = state.ingredients[action.payload.index];
      return {};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Ingredient Model

```
export class Ingredient {
  constructor(public name: string, public amount: number) {
  }
}



Error: src/app/shopping-list/store/shopping-list.reducer.ts:30:59 - error TS2339: Property 'index' does not exist on type 'Ingredient | { index: number; ingredient: Ingredient; }'.
  Property 'index' does not exist on type 'Ingredient'.

30       const ingredient = state.ingredients[action.payload.index];
```

Comment: Show the model for Ingredient

Comment: @R.Richards i have updated the question to include the model.

Comment: you have name and amount defined for Ingredient, where is `index` defined? Also, what action is triggering this error?

Comment: I figured out the issue. The issue is where this is defined. readonly type: string = ADD_INGREDIENT; It should not have string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect implementation

```
export class AddIngredient implements Action {
  readonly type: string = ADD_INGREDIENT;

  constructor(public payload: Ingredient) {
  }
}
```

Correct Implementation

```
export class AddIngredient implements Action {
  readonly type = ADD_INGREDIENT;

  constructor(public payload: Ingredient) {
  }
}
```